# Criar relação 1:1 no Query Browser

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Gostaria de saber como criar relações 1:1 no Query Browser.

Não sei se estou certo, mas ele cria relações 1:n ao criar *foreign keys*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na imagem abaixo você pode ver um exemplo de relação 1:1 no Query Browser:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Lembre-se que o *engine* da tabela deve suportar relacionamentos. (Quer dizer: precisa ser **InnoDB** ao invés de **MyISAM**.)

Neste exemplo, cada "assinante" tem uma "configuracao", portanto definimos uma chave estrangeira (*foreign key*) na tabela `configuracoes`, usando o campo `id_assinante`:

- Na aba "Foreign Key", clique no "+" em cor verde
- Estabeleça um nome para a chave (Key Name)
- Diga à qual tabela se relaciona (Refer. Table)
- Na listagem "Column / Foreign Column", você pode arrastar a "Column" da tabela atual, e na "Foreign Column" correspondente, coloque o nome do campo da outra tabela (no exemplo, ambos têm o mesmo nome: `id_assinante`)
- Você ainda pode determinar o que acontece nesta tabela caso alguma mudança aconteça na outra tabela:

  - "On Delete" determina o que acontece aqui caso a coluna relacionada seja deletada na outra tabela (o que acontece em configurações se o assinante for deletado)
  - "On Update" determina o que acontece aqui caso a coluna relacionada seja alterada na outra tabela (o que acontece em configurações se o id_assinante for modificado)

---

Se a relação é 1:1 ou 1:n depende da utilização que será feita - no banco de dados a relação via *foreign key* é a mesma.

Para forçar que seja 1:1, vá na aba "Indices" e inclua um índice do tipo `UNIQUE` para o campo `id_assinante` na mesma tabela onde a chave estrangeira foi definida.

Assim, não podendo haver mais de uma "configuração" com um mesmo `id_assinante`, iremos garantir uma relação 1:1.

---

Conforme solicitado, eis o comando SQL de criação da tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE  `pdm`.`configuracoes` (
  `id_configuracao` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_assinante` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `assinatura_ativa` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_configuracao`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_assinante_UNIQUE` (`id_assinante`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_configuracoes_assinantes` FOREIGN KEY (`id_assinante`)
    REFERENCES `assinantes` (`id_assinante`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Para garantir que seja exclusivamente 1:1 (isto é, não seja aceito 1:0 que indica a existência de um registro que não está relacionado com nenhum da outra tabela) adicione a restrição NOT NULL ao campo chave estrangeira.

Comment: Bem lembrado. O campo `id_asinante` no exemplo acima, de fato, é `NOT NULL`, seguindo essa restrição.

Comment: Tem algum exemplo de como eu poderia fazer isso usando apenas queries?

Comment: Incluí a query no final da resposta.

Comment: Me surgiu uma dúvida: o `\`id_assinante_UNIQUE\`` é uma constraint, porém implícita?